# How do I store the images instead of base64 in Laravel

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, base64, tinymce

Good Day. Please, I need your assistance. Building a laravel website in which tinymce is/was implemented in a some textareas. The challenge is that if images are uploaded in the editor, they are stored as base64 encoding. This slows down the server. I had to change my data type to longtext in my database. How do I store the images instead of base64? And how do I read the stored images.

My codes are shown below
My Controller

```
public function create(Request $request){


        $categories = BlogCategory::all();
        $tags = Tag::all();

        if($request->isMethod('post')){

            //dd($request);
            $data = $request->except('name');
            $post = new Post;
            //Title
            $post->title = $request->title;
            //Slug
            $post->publish_date = new Carbon;
            $slug = $this->createSlug($request->title);
            $post->slug = $slug;

            //Category
            if($request->category_id == "Choose Category")
            {
                Session::flash('failure','Please Select A Category To Proceed!');
                return redirect()->back();
            }else{
                $post->category_id = $request->category_id;
            }


            //Body
            $post->body = $request->body;

            //Author
            if(isset($request->author)){
                $post->author = $request->author;
                $post->author_slug = Str::slug($post->author,'-');
            }else{
                $post->author = "";
                $post->author_slug = "";
            }

            //User ID
            $post->user_id = Auth::user()->id;

            //Keywords
            if(isset($request->keywords)){
                $post->keywords = $request->keywords;
            }else{
                $post->keywords = "";
            }

            //Description
            if(isset($request->description)){
                $post->description = $request->description;
            }else{
                $post->description = "";
            }

            //Publish
            if(isset($request->publish)){
                if($request->publish == 'draft'){
                    $post->publish = 0;
                }elseif($request->publish == 'publish'){
                    $post->publish = 1;
                    $post->publish_date = new Carbon;
                }
            }

            //Comment
            if(isset($request->comments)){
                if($request->comments = "on"){
                    $post->comment = 1;
                }
            }

            //Image
            if($request->hasFile('image')){
                $img_temp = $request->file('image');
                if($img_temp->isValid()){

                    $extension = $img_temp->getClientOriginalExtension();
                    $filename = 'mohvisuals'.rand(111,9999).'.'.$extension;
                    $large_image_path = 'images/backend_images/posts/large/'.$filename;
                    $medium_image_path = 'images/backend_images/posts/medium/'.$filename;


                    //Resize Images
                    Image::make($img_temp)->save($large_image_path);
                    Image::make($img_temp)->fit(500,400)->save($medium_image_path);

                    //Store Images
                    $post->image =$filename;
                }
            }

            $post->save();
            $post->tags()->sync($request->tags,false);
            Session::flash('success',' Post Created Successfully!');
            return redirect()->back();

        }

        return view('back_end.blog.posts.create')->with(compact('categories','tags'));

 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your title/description says something, but your code says something else.

- To store **the file in** database, the column type must be BINARY/BLOB.
- To store **the filename** in database and the **file on** disk, colum type should be VARCHAR relative to the maximum filename length.

Do not convert files to base64 unless they're small, as their size will increase around x3 times.

To store file **in** database you can use this code. Inside your controller:

```
if ($request->hasFile('file'))
{
    // If you want to resize the image, use the following method to get temporary file's path.
    $request->file('file')->getPathName(); 

    // `get()` retrieves file's content in binary mode
    $post->image = request->file('file')->get(); 
}
```